# Flutter macOS Desktop App: How do I get the path to the app package Resources folder?

Tags: flutter

When I place some folder in my project's root, I can access it e.g. with

```
Directory('html'));
```

But this does not work in production. Placing it in MyApp/Contents/Resources/html has no effect.

How can I get the App's path to Resources?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This code gets the absolute path to MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/html where ever the app is installed:

```
  var docRoot = 'html';
  var urlSeg = List.from(File(Platform.resolvedExecutable).uri.pathSegments);
  urlSeg = urlSeg.sublist(0,urlSeg.length - 2);
  urlSeg.add('Resources');
  docRoot = "/${urlSeg.join('/')}/html";
```